# I am having trouble understanding the Leader-Line js documentation

Tags: javascript, documentation

I am trying to create code that will draw a line from point a to point b using the leaderline library. https://github.com/anseki/leader-line

It looks like the section I need to reference is under Methods

```
self = line.show([showEffectName[, animOptions]])
```

where `showEffectName: 'draw'` and `animOptions: {duration: 500, timing: [0.58, 0, 0.42, 1]}`

Here is an example shown using a button to show/hide the line

```
var line = new LeaderLine(startElement, endElement, {hide: true});
showButton.addEventListener('click', function() { line.show(); }, false);
hideButton.addEventListener('click', function() { line.hide(); }, false);
```

How do I implement the self= code into the button? I'm not even sure what self= is supposed to mean. The below code does not work

```
var line = new LeaderLine(startElement, endElement, {hide: true});
line.show() = line.show({showEffectName:'draw'}, {animOptions: {duration: 3000, timing: 'linear'}});
startElement.addEventListener('click', function() { line.show(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for

```js
line.show('draw', {
  animOptions: {
    duration: 3000,
    timing: [0.5, 0, 1, 0.42]
  }
})
```

And now you can call this in any function

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  line.show('draw', {
    animOptions: {
      duration: 3000,
      timing: [0.5, 0, 1, 0.42]
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you have to put only value like below.

```
var line = new LeaderLine(startElement, endElement, {hide: true});

startElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
  line.show("draw", {duration: 3000, timing: 'linear'});
});
```